# ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version

Tags: java, android, android-studio

## estoy tratando de compilar una aplicacion que utiliza firebase authentication y base de datos

================================================================

### Texto random porque no se que mas poner

### Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec,

Este es mi build.grandle(Proyect)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to      all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Este es mi build.grandle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pc.proyectofinal"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
   }

  dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.1.0"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1"
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

ERROR OBTENIDO

```
   ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
   1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
  15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

 The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
 ifact with the issue.
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@{strictly 16.1.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop@{strictly 16.0.0}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.1
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@{strictly 16.0.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@{strictly 16.0.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 16.0.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@{strictly 16.0.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@{strictly 16.0.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection@{strictly 16.0.0}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@{strictly 16.0.4}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@{strictly 16.0.1} 
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@{strictly 16.0.0}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@16.0.4
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-common@{strictly 16.0.3}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@16.0.1
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl@{strictly 16.0.1} 
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats@{strictly 15.0.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector@{strictly 16.0.0}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop@{strictly 16.0.0}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@{strictly 15.0.1}
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags@{strictly 15.0.1}

 For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with  ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
 endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
 github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding  "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.
```

Answer (score -2):

Yo creo que el problema puede ser que ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec,

Comment: El estafador resulto estafado :v  , pero gracias, ya me funciono xd